# Is it valid to have a certificate chain contained within START/END CERTIFICATE labels in a PEM file?

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate, x509, pem

I have a pem file that is structured as follows:

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
<leaf cert details in Base64>
<root cert details in Base64>
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

instead of how I would typically expect it to be structured:

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
<leaf cert details in Base64>
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
<root cert details in Base64>
-----END CERTIFICATE-----.
```

Is the former file valid according to any RFC?

Comment: I would suggest that what you have is created by some software not conforming to standards. Having multiple certificate within a single CERTIFICATE PEM envelope is wrong and I doubt that any standard software is able to interpret this as multiple certificates.  I cannot actually find a reference for how multiple certificates should be encoded since I don't think there is such a thing. There is only a reference for single certificates, see https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7468#section-5

Comment: @SteffenUllrich: section 1 of 7468 states as an advantage of PEM over binary/DER "a user may concatenate several certificates to form a certificate chain with copy-and-paste operations" but that's neither precise enough to implement nor normative (no 2119 capitalized keyword).